# No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.LeanBack'

Tags: android

I am porting Android sample tv input to our target platform. While building on android studio or command line, following error is observed wrt to Leanback library. The lib is part of android.mk. But still it's unable to find Theme. Leanback declared under `res/values/themes.xml`

```xml
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.LeanBack">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.LeanBack'.

Comment: change it to android:Theme.Leanback.FormWizard

Comment: Which Api Level Used..

Comment: Using android:theme.Leanback.FormWizard fixed the build issue. Can this be elaborated?